# Do I have to override Object toString to give a <tr an id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to pass a parameter to `optionThings` that will be used as an ID for the given row.

This code doesn't work.

**Where am I wrong?**

```
var OptionRow = React.createClass({
    optionThings: function(rootSymbol){  
        //process.stdout.write("Render Option");

        return (  
            <tbody>            
            <tr id=rootSymbol.toString()>
             ....
```

Comment: If you are returning `html` it should be a `string`.it should be In qoutes

Comment: imo, it should be `<tr id={rootSymbol}>`

Comment: @Mairja, if I quote "rootSymbol" the id will be "rootSymbo", not the content of rootSymbol, e.g., "PG".

Comment: @thomas that works. Thanks.